# I'm having problems with toggling my navigation bar. I'm Using the latest Bootstrap v5.1.3

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

new here and sorry if I mess up real bad, don't fully know how this works yet. Here is my code though, as I said my navbar-toggler wont pop down and show my links, I hope this makes sense somewhat as I'm still new to coding. I've tried adding older script sources and older bootstrap links but nothing works so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarTogglerDemo0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>



    <!-- Title -->

    <div>
      <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
      <button type="button">Download</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright TinDog</p>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code I think Problem will be solved

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="title">
        <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Download</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Title -->
        <div>
            <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Features -->
    <section id="features">

        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </section>
    <!-- Testimonials -->
    <section id="testimonials">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

        <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->
    </section>
    <!-- Press -->
    <section id="press">
        <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
        <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
        <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
        <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

    </section>
    <!-- Pricing -->
    <section id="pricing">
        <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
        <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

        <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
        <h2>Free</h2>
        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

        <h3>Labrador</h3>
        <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

        <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
        <p>Pirority Listing</p>
        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

    </section>

    <!-- Call to Action -->

    <section id="cta">

        <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>

    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer id="footer">
        <p>© Copyright TinDog</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey man you're a legend! it works! Do you mind explaining to me how you fixed it? You don't have to as you already saved me here but I'd love to know how I can fix it the next time.

Comment: Follow this link for js and css cdn link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Try to understand bootstrap navbar from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/